# Why does the water diffuse at right angles in my coffee?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, diffusion

I purchase an espresso shot each morning at my local coffee shop, and I usually water it down slightly to take the edge off as well as to cool it. Recently, I have noticed that when I pour the cold water in, it seems that the surface of my espresso is suddenly disturbed in a lattice-like configuration
\begin{align*}
\nearrow \searrow \nearrow \searrow \\
\nwarrow\swarrow\nwarrow\swarrow
\end{align*}
i.e., water moving up at a $45^\circ$ angle and down at a $45^\circ$ angle along the surface. Googling `water diffusion in coffee` has been fruitless unfortunately. Any thoughts? Regards, Zvpunry.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the coffee? It's not clear from your illustration what you're observing.

Comment: My first suspicion is that you have neat little convection cells...

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're referring to, but I'll go make myself an espresso and watch.  This might be fun to animate with 3D graphics, to show what's really going on.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see anything like that. I'll go make yet another cup of espresso....  Ok, some questions.  Do you see this only with the espresso, or with other fluids (milk, lemonade, tea, beer, soup ...?)  How much fluid in what size and shape of cup? How are you pouring it in - a nice steady stream (diameter?) or splashy drops?   Is this straight espresso with no additives such as cream, flavor syrups?  A video would be helpful, even a crappy cell phone one.

Comment: Thanks all for your input. I'm going to post a video of this soon, at least by tomorrow (if I have another espresso shot today that might be the end of me).

Comment: @DarenW I have only noticed this with cold water into hot drinks. It isn't specific to how concentrated the espresso is: I observe the same thing with an Americano. I'm pouring a steady stream of cold water, diameter about half a centimeter, and it is straight espresso no additives.

Comment: Re: close votes. I don't think the pouring of one fluid into another of a different temperature/density is "too localized." Almost certainly the names of the liquids don't matter here - coffee is also just water, conveniently colored for the purposes of experimentation.

Comment: @Chris it's possible the reasoning is that this is a very specific real-life situation. How many people does it really help to know why the surface of liquid in a cup vibrates in a particular pattern? If the question could be rewritten in a way that makes it more generally useful, it could definitely be good.